# Simple Injector with ASP.NET Core With Full .NET Framework (.NET 4.7)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I am using ASP.NET Core with the full .NET framework and want to try Simple Injector. In the Nuget manager, I see so many options for Simple Injetcor e.g. "SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC" and "SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" I don't see any diff in release or dependencies.

Please suggest which NuGet should be used based on the framework setup I am using.

Comment: I guess something's wrong here. It is impossible to use cross-platform Core and full Framework. Choose one of them.

Comment: Which package should I use in  Asp.Net Core API(With .Net Framework)?  simpleinjector or SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc. Please note it's just an API

Answer (score 0):

The the [ASP.NET Core integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore) of the Simple Injector documentation describes which NuGet package to use. See the first paragraph, but don't forget to read the whole page.

But to be specific, [SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC) is the full integration package, which "adds tag helper integration on top of the core functionality," and depends on [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/). The core integration functionality is part of  [SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/) and "includes control and view component integration."

To integrate Simple Injector with ASP.NET Core MVC, you should use the `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC` integration package, unless you don't need tag helper integration and want to limit the number of dependencies on `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages in your application, which might be an issue when you are running inside a (Docker) container. In that case,  use `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have read the whole page. The limitations around auto cross-wiring of collections seem scary. Can you please provide an how manual cross wiring is done?

Comment: Which of the limitations do you find scare? Manual cross-wiring can be done using the `CrossWire<TService>` extension method.

Comment: "Collections (i.e. IEnumerable<T>) will not be auto cross-wired because of unbridgeable differences between how Simple Injector and ASP.NET Core’s configuration system handle collections" This one feels restrictive.

Comment: That doesn't mean it is impossible; it simply means you will have to resolve the collection manually.